# Accordion (html and css only) works on Chrome but not on Edge & Mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a project and I use an accordion that I made with this website: https://accordionslider.com/

It works perfectly on Chrome but not on Firefox and edge, when I use my custom one I just have a gap between my navbar and the rest of my content. When I use the default one of the website I have a thin line in the middle of where it should be. You can test with the HTML/CSS of the website I provide

For information:

- Mozilla Firefox : 73.0
- Google Chrome : 80.0
- Microsoft Edge : 44

And I'm working with Angular but I don't think it have any impact since it's a CSS/HTML problem

```css
.accordion {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion-select {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.accordion-title {
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-title:not(:nth-last-child(2))::after {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.accordion-title span {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease 0.1s;
}

.accordion-select:checked+.accordion-title+.accordion-content {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Generated styles starts here */

.accordion {
  border-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
}

.accordion-title,
.accordion-select {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #7f8787;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.accordion-select {
  margin-bottom: -65px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.accordion-title:not(:nth-last-child(2))::after {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.accordion-select:hover+.accordion-title,
.accordion-select:checked+.accordion-title {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.accordion-title span {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-writing-mode: lr-tb;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0);
  padding-left: 33px;
  padding-right: 33px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.accordion-content {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #7f8787;
  height: 280px;
  margin-bottom: -280px;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <input type="radio" name="select" class="accordion-select" checked />
  <div class="accordion-title"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">Content</div>
  <input type="radio" name="select" class="accordion-select" />
  <div class="accordion-title"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">Content</div>
  <input type="radio" name="select" class="accordion-select" />
  <div class="accordion-title"><span>Title</span></div>
  <div class="accordion-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

[image: Chrome render]
[image: Firefox render]

Comment: Please add your code as [mcve]

Comment: Can you please re-create this in JSFiddle?

Comment: @AskYous https://jsfiddle.net/gdv2q8pz/

Comment: Thanks @Pilum. The JSFiddle example worked for me in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. Same browser versions as you, except Edge was 44.1.

Comment: Could you possibly show a screenshot or something of this code not executing properly in your browsers? I copied and pasted both your code and the website's code and they both worked fine in Chrome, Edge Chromium (Edge is going the way of the dodo), and Firefox. No issues anywhere.

Comment: @Pilum, Is the issue solved or still persist? Let us know about the status of the issue. If it is resolved please share the solution for the issue. if the issue persists then we can try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: The issue is solved, it was a padding issue

Comment: Thanks for informing us about the status of the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with MS Edge, Google Chrome and Firefox browsers. Based on my testing results, I found that all 3 browsers are showing similar output. I am not able to find any difference or issue in output.

Here is my testing result:

[image]

If you are still facing the issue then I suggest you try to provide more information about it. We will again try to check for the issue.